# How can I vertically align a div within bootstrap 5 carousel on all screen sizes?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox, bootstrap-5

I would like the text div inside a bootstrap 5 carousel to be vertically aligned (centered) on large and small (mobile) screens.

The site is here...

https://bootstrapmade.com/demo/templates/Flattern

Here is the html for the div. The div that needs to be centered is has the css class

```
#hero .carousel-container {
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-end;
    justify-content: center;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 60px;
    top: 110px;
    left: 50px;
    right: 50px;
}
```

Here is the html for the carousel...

```
<section id="hero">
    <div id="heroCarousel" data-bs-interval="5000" class="carousel slide carousel-fade pointer-event" data-bs-ride="carousel">

      <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">

        <!-- Slide 1 -->
        <div class="carousel-item active" style="background-image: url(assets/img/slide/slide-1.jpg);">
          <div class="carousel-container">
            <div class="carousel-content animate__animated animate__fadeInUp">
              <h2>Welcome to <span>Flattern</span></h2>
              <p>Ut velit est quam dolor ad a aliquid qui aliquid. Sequi ea ut et est quaerat sequi nihil ut aliquam. Occaecati alias dolorem mollitia ut. Similique ea voluptatem. Esse doloremque accusamus repellendus deleniti vel. Minus et tempore modi architecto.</p>
              <div class="text-center"><a href="" class="btn-get-started">Read More</a></div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Slide 2 -->
        <div class="carousel-item" style="background-image: url(assets/img/slide/slide-2.jpg);">
          <div class="carousel-container">
            <div class="carousel-content animate__animated animate__fadeInUp">
              <h2>Lorem Ipsum Dolor</h2>
              <p>Ut velit est quam dolor ad a aliquid qui aliquid. Sequi ea ut et est quaerat sequi nihil ut aliquam. Occaecati alias dolorem mollitia ut. Similique ea voluptatem. Esse doloremque accusamus repellendus deleniti vel. Minus et tempore modi architecto.</p>
              <div class="text-center"><a href="" class="btn-get-started">Read More</a></div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Slide 3 -->
        <div class="carousel-item" style="background-image: url(assets/img/slide/slide-3.jpg);">
          <div class="carousel-container">
            <div class="carousel-content animate__animated animate__fadeInUp">
              <h2>Sequi ea ut et est quaerat</h2>
              <p>Ut velit est quam dolor ad a aliquid qui aliquid. Sequi ea ut et est quaerat sequi nihil ut aliquam. Occaecati alias dolorem mollitia ut. Similique ea voluptatem. Esse doloremque accusamus repellendus deleniti vel. Minus et tempore modi architecto.</p>
              <div class="text-center"><a href="" class="btn-get-started">Read More</a></div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>

      <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#heroCarousel" role="button" data-bs-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon bx bx-left-arrow" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      </a>

      <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#heroCarousel" role="button" data-bs-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon bx bx-right-arrow" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      </a>

      <ol class="carousel-indicators" id="hero-carousel-indicators"><li data-bs-target="#heroCarousel" data-bs-slide-to="0" class="active"></li><li data-bs-target="#heroCarousel" data-bs-slide-to="1"></li><li data-bs-target="#heroCarousel" data-bs-slide-to="2"></li></ol>

    </div>
  </section>
```

Thanks for your help

I tried removing position absolute from #hero .carousel-container while adding aligns-items-center to the parent div (carousel-item) but it does not seem to help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many way using which you can vertically center that div but the way css you have use and i assume that you have knowledge of css positioning property so just change your css with given below.

```
#hero .carousel-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  justify-content: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 100%;
}
```

Hope that work for you :)